# Web scraping nested comments on Reddit using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, reddit

This code gets the page. My problem is I need to scrape the content of users comments not the number of comments. It is nested inside the number of comments section but I am not sure how I can access the link and parse through and scrape the user comments.

```
request_list = []
id_list = [0]

for i in range(0,200,25): 
    response = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/?count="+str(i)+"&after="+str(id_list[-1]), headers = {'User-agent':'No Bot'})  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml') 
    request_list.append(soup)
    id_list.append(soup.find_all('div', attrs={'data-type': 'link'})[-1]['data-fullname'])
    print(i, id_list)
    if i%100 == 0: 
        time.sleep(1)
```

The code below I tried writing a function that is supposed to access the nested comments but I have no clue.

```
def extract_comment_contents(request_list):    
    comment_contents_list = []   
    for i in request_list:
        if response.status_code == 200: 
            for each in i.find_all('a', attrs={'data-inbound-url': '/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/'}): 
                comment_contents_list.append(each.text)
        else:
            print("Call failed at request ", i)           
    return comment_contents_list



fetch_comment_contents_list = extract_comment_contents(request_list)

print(fetch_comment_contents_list)
```

Comment: Reddit has a well-defined API, and makes sure that anything that you want to do is available there.  You should use the API instead - it will be better on their servers and **much** easier for you than web scraping.  It gets even easier with Python because you can use [PRAW](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 2):

For each thread, you need to send another request to get the comments page. The url for the comments page can be found using `soup.find_all('a', class_='bylink comments may-blank')`. This will give all the `a` tags that have to url for the comments page. I'll show you one example to get to the comments page.

```
r = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/?count=0&after=0')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

for comments_tag in soup.find_all('a', class_='bylink comments may-blank', href=True):
    url = comments_tag['href']
    r2 = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r2.text, 'lxml')
    # Your job is to parse this soup object and get all the comments.
```